# Cleanest way to make a lambda that returns a const reference to a data member?

Tags: c++, stl

With the advent of `std::views::transform` and the addition of *projections* to `std::algorithm`, it becomes common to want a function that returns a `const` reference to a data member of its argument. For example, the following code to chain together containers:

```
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

struct S
{
    std::vector<int> v;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<S> structs;
    auto get_v = [](S const &s) -> auto& { return s.v; };
    auto chain = structs | std::views::transform(get_v);
    auto joined = chain | std::views::join;
}
```

This works, but the lambda to construct `chain` is a little clunky. Is there a nicer way to do it?

As an ideal for comparison, in Python we could write

```
chain = (s.v for s in structs)
```

Comment: I don't think you can get much terser than `using std::views::transform; auto chain = structs | transform([](auto&&s){return s.v;};`

Comment: @MooingDuck your version doesn't compile on g++ 10 when used in the example above. I am struggling to read the error message, but I believe it is because you return `s.v` by value instead of by reference, so it violates the constraint `std::is_reference_v<ranges::range_reference_t<V>>` of `join`. I used the `-> auto&` annotation to fix this.